# Confused about garbage collection

Tags: java

In the following code how many objects are eligible for garbage collection after executing line 7?
In my opinion 1 object that is z is eligible. Is is right?

```
public class Tester 
{ 
  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {

    Integer x = new Integer(3000);   
    Integer y = new Integer(4000);   
    Integer z = new Integer(5000);

    Object a = x;   
    x = y;  
    y = z;
    z = null; //line 7 
   }
}
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't confuse a reference with an object. The object is the actual item that has been created, the reference is simply a name that refers to it.

You've created three objects, let's call them `3000`, `4000` and `5000`. You've also set up references as follows:

```
Ref    Object
---    ------
 x  ->  3000
 y  ->  4000
 z  ->  5000
```

After the assignments, you end up with:

```
Ref    Object
---    ------
 a  ->  3000
 x  ->  4000
 y  ->  5000
 z
```

Hence none of the *objects* are subject to garbage collection. Every single one still has a reference to it.

---

By way of contrast, if you were to remove the line:

```
Object a = x;
```

then the assignments would then result in:

```
Ref    Object
---    ------
        3000
 x  ->  4000
 y  ->  5000
 z
```

and the *object* we called `3000` would be eligible for garbage collection, since you no longer have any way to access it.

---

And, as an aside, you may want to consider the fact that one of the major reasons automated garbage collection was created was to make these sorts of questions moot :-) Generally (though there are of course exceptions), you shouldn't *need* to worry about what objects are subject to collection.

Answer (score 2):

**None of the objects are eligible for Garbage Collections**.

Every object has a live references. `z` is not an Object, it's just a reference. You have moved the references only.

Answer (score 1):

x, y and z aren't objects - they are references to objects.

Informally, any object is eligible for garbage collection when there's no way you could possibly ever access it any more. After running this code, x refers to the 3000 object, y refers to the 4000 object, and z refers to the 5000 object. The 3000 object cannot be collected, because you could use it, e.g. `System.out.println(a);`. The 4000 object cannot be collected, because you could use it through x, e.g. `System.out.println(x);`. The 5000 object cannot be collected, because you could use it through z.

After `main` returns, all of those objects are eligible for garbage collection, because you can't access them after that.

Answer (score 1):

z won't be eligible for GC at line 7. It is because in line 6, y is refrencing the object which was previously refrenced by z. So even thought you have made `z=null`, y is still refrencing the object created in the heap ie. `new Integer(5000);`